# Why are some "o" + consonant + "er" verbs not conjugated into "ue" + consonant + "e"?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

As the title says. An "O" before the last syllable (-er or -ir) is often turned into "ue" when conjugating, e.g. *puede*, *duerme*, *vuele*.

Verbs ending in -ar don't: *nota*, *vota*, ...

But *poner*, *comer*, etc. ends in -er, so why aren't they *puene*, *cueme*?

Comment: Also, note that "vuele" comes from "volar", so some verbs ending with "ar" also change the "o". _Soñar > sueño, tronar > trueno_. And also with "ir": _morir > muero_. So the question could be just why sometimes an "o" syllable changes to "ue" in verbs and others don't.

Comment: AFAIK this alternation is much more common among *-er* and *-ir* verbs, which are also on the whole more irregular. But @Charlie is right. You'll find this outside verbs too (e.g. *tiempo* vs. *temporal*).

Comment: don't expect to apply rules on how to conjugate words in spanish, even for a spanish native speaker, sometimes  is hard to find how a words is an specific tense (grab a dictionary)

Comment: I agree with @Mike. The rule is "there are no rules". Listen and read a lot and you will get it, but don't try to memorize rules. That will only keep you from learning. (my 2 cents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verbs that alternate between *o* and *ue* (like the verbs that alternate between *e* and *ie/u*) are the result of a phonetic change that happened to the *short* /o/ and /e/ in Latin as it transitioned to modern languages (the vowels in Latin could be either long or short).

For the most part, if you know the Latin word has a short vowel, you can predict that the change will happen, although it's not a perfect system (*correr* or *responder* should change, but don't, at least not in Spanish).

Comment: lol... expecting to apply rules to know how the words are conjugated, 
is actually the opposite, you see how they are conjugated to understand their origin,

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called **irregularity** in languages, that means that some of the members of a group, in this case the group of verbs, don't follow the **regular** canonical pattern.